# How can I programmatically obtain reliable backtraces in spite of optimization?

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-optimization, backtrace

The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html) for libc's backtrace related functionality states the following restriction.

> Note that certain compiler optimizations may interfere with obtaining
>   a valid backtrace. Function inlining causes the inlined function to
>   not have a stack frame; tail call optimization replaces one stack
>   frame with another; frame pointer elimination will stop backtrace from
>   interpreting the stack contents correctly.

I've also observed incorrect return addresses coming out of the `backtrace` function call when compiling large programs on gcc with `-O3`. However, it seems that `gdb` is still able to print the correct backtrace despite the optimization.

Is there a programmatic way to obtain correct backtraces with optimizations turned on?

Comment: gdb probably uses the debug information to fill in the *missing* stack frames.

Answer (score 1):

`backtrace`'s algorith is extremely primitive as it relies on frame pointers to restore the stacktrace. As such it will not work on any modern platform unless you build your code with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` (which would hurt performance).

A much better alternative is to use libunwind or libbacktrace and compile with `-funwind-tables`.